Applications of the outer product in shaders
I've been reading through the specification of OpenGL ES 3.20 and found a built-in "outerProduct" function for computing the outer product of two vectors, specifically, outerProduct(a,b) = $a\cdot b^T$.
What applications is this intended for? That is, why would someone want to use the outerProduct function in a shader?
I recall seeing this sort of construction in quantum physics, and the Wikipedia page suggests it is also used for signal processing and image compression without going into detail.


You can construct the orthogonal projection matrix onto $u$ as $P= uu^T$ if $u$ is unit length, otherwise it is $P_{u,u^{\perp}}=u(u^Tu)^{-1}u^T = \frac{uu^T}{u^Tu}$.

If you have $P_{u,v^{\perp}}=u(v^Tu)^{-1}v^T = \frac{uv^T}{v^Tu}$ that's an oblique projection onto $u$ along the perpendicular hyperplane to $v$.

If you have a matrix $A$ and its singular value decomposition $A=USV^T$ you can write $A= \sum_{r=1}^{rank(A)} \sigma_i u_iv_i^T$, ditto for eigendecomposition of a symmetric matrix $A=\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i v_iv_i^T$. You can "compress" the matrix by dropping terms from the sum with smaller singular values $\sigma_i$.

The structure tensor in image processing is computed through the outer product of the gradient and a subsequent convolution: $K_{\rho} * \nabla u \nabla u^T$.

You can compute the covariance matrix between random vectors $U$ and $V$ as $\mathbb{E}[(U-\mathbb{E}[U])(V-\mathbb{E}[V])^T] \approx \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i=1}^M (u_i - \mu_u)(v_i-\mu_v)^T$. Here $u_i, v_i$ are randomly sampled vectors with the same density as $U$ and $V$, and $\mu_u, \mu_v$ are approximations of the means of those. Typically you perform an eigendecomposition on the covariance matrix for analysis purposes.


